# List of FLEX options?

Tags: options, flex-options

PHLX advertise something called FLEX options:

http://www.nasdaqtrader.com/Micro.aspx?id=phlxflexproductspecs

How I read this: if someone w/ a lot of money wants to write their own 
options chain, they can do so, and trade it over PHLX.

How do I get a list of FLEX options? PHLX lists some ways herE:

http://www.nasdaqtrader.com/Micro.aspx?id=PHLXEquityOptions#fo

but I couldn't get *any* of the 3 listed sites to work: I either get 
unrelated quotes or "equity not found" errors.

Comment: Wow, I forgot that stack lists the last time you visit a given stack site. OK, the info was great, but isn't it more about how people can create options, not an actual list of FLEX options that's currently being traded at this very moment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're all in one place.

The OCC provides: http://www.optionsclearing.com/webapps/flex-reports

Answer (score 2):

The three *sites* mentioned in the second link are all professional trading workstations, not public web sites.

There may not be free quotes available.

Comment: OK, what about a site that just lists them w/o quotes?